# Why does ㅗ *o* sometimes sound like ㅜ *u*?

Tags: pronunciation

When I listen to [오 on Naver Dict](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%98%A4) (or [오다](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%98%A4%EB%8B%A4) or [오늘](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%98%A4%EB%8A%98)), it sounds the same as [우](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%9A%B0). 오 sounds like a [u] sound, not an [o] sound like in [Spanish *como* [komo]](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/como). (Click the speech icon with round, not vertical, sound waves for a human-recorded sound rather than text-to-speech.) Maybe 우 sounds a bit more emphatic, but it doesn't sound very different. In contrast, [소](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%86%8C), [요³](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%9A%94), and [포](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%ED%8F%AC), and the text-to-speech 오 definitely sound like [o]. [코](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%BD%94) and Wikipedia's [[o]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_back_rounded_vowel) also sounds like [u], although if I listen to it while thinking [o] in my head, it starts to sound more like [o]. But the vowels in 오, [노](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EB%85%B8), and [모](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EB%AC%B4) sound to me unambiguously like [u].

Is ㅗ more closed and thus sounds more like ㅜ in some certain phonological environments (after certain consonants, depending on vowel length, etc.), or is it more just that it varies by speaker or dialect? Would it be wrong to say ㅗ the way the text-to-speech says it? When ㅗ sounds like [u] to me, is ㅜ somehow even more closed, or are they really indistinguishable?

Answer (score 2):

The slipperiness of vowels!

To my ear, there is a difference between [오](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%98%A4) and [우](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%9A%B0) on Naver, and also between the voices that are there for [오](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%98%A4) too. They are very close though.

There are several factors at work here:

- The same vowel phoneme /o/ can have a different phonetic range between different speech varieties (so IPA may not be *as* phonetic as one might expect). This is well known amongst *hispanohablantes* learning Italian, where distinguishing /o/ and /ɔ/ is an issue. Looking at the two formant charts for [Spanish](http://liceu.uab.es/%7Ejoaquim/phonetics/fon_anal_acus/caract_acust.html) and Korean, we can see that Spanish /o/ lies around both Korean /o/ and /ɔ~ʌ/.
- The length of vowels can change the "quality" of the vowel somewhat. In Standard South Korean, the long /oː/ is phonetically more closed than the short /o/. This is likely to be rather minor in actual speech, but dictionaries tend to preserve former standards.
- There has been a vowel shift happening in modern South Korean, especially in the Greater Seoul area, with /o/ becoming [u] and /u/ [fronting](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/42544/BerrjodMaster.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) to [ʉ]. The contrast is [weakening](https://www.yoonjungkang.com/uploads/1/1/6/2/11625099/asa_2015_vowels_poster_final.pdf), however, with fronting of /u/ not being universal.